# Moving from single-boot Windows 10 to another single-boot Windows 10, with transitional dual-boot

Tags: boot, windows-10, multi-boot

I installed Windows 10 on my HDD, the HDD is dying now (sometimes stops working), I installed separate Windows 10 on SSD. I want only OS on the SSD to exist eventually, but in the mean time I prefer having dual-boot, just in case I forgot about some files or configs.

When I start my computer, a menu appears with two OSs. The first one on SSD (if I click it, it boots instantly), the second on HDD (it restarts and loads the corresponding OS). It's fine, I don't reboot often anyway.

**Problem:** When I disable HDD and tell BIOS to load from SSD, computer fails to load. I see this message:

> Reboot and select proper boot device
>   or insert bood media in selected boot device and press a key

**Question:** What do I need to do to make OS on SSD self-sufficient when HDD is unavailable? What is the correct way of "moving" to another drive, and how to recover now?

---

Running `bootsect` within either OS results in this (from what I've read, this error doesn't matter much):

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>bootsect /nt60 e: /mbr /force
Target volumes will be updated with BOOTMGR compatible bootcode.

E: (\\?\Volume{296441a0-27e8-11e5-bfd5-005056c00008})

    Updated NTFS filesystem bootcode.  The update may be unreliable since the
    volume could not be dismounted during the update:
        Access is denied.

\??\PhysicalDrive0

    Successfully updated disk bootcode.

Bootcode was successfully updated on all targeted volumes.
```

(I don't have a bootable USB, so didn't try running `bootrec` yet.)

Output from `bcdedit / enum`:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {6b79064e-2ba2-11e6-a537-dddf63be2e7f}
displayorder            {default}
                        {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {default}
device                  partition=E:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=E:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {6b79064e-2ba2-11e6-a537-dddf63be2e7f}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {bbddb5d2-aaec-11e5-a2e4-ab39cc78a083}
recoveryenabled         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {79aca280-aaec-11e5-a2e4-ab39cc78a083}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto
```

It looks like the boot manager thing resides on HDD and I guess I'd prefer it on SSD, but I don't know how to do this.

And finally, `diskpart`/`list volume`/`exit`:

```
  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     E   Fast         NTFS   Partition    119 GB  Healthy    Pagefile
  Volume 1         System Rese  NTFS   Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 2     C   System       NTFS   Partition    930 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 3                      NTFS   Partition    450 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 4     D   Data         NTFS   Partition   2794 GB  Healthy
  Volume 5     G   Storage Ath  NTFS   Partition   1397 GB  Healthy
```

In Disk Management, this "System Reserved" partition on HDD is marked as "System", "Active" and "Primary". SSD doesn't have it. From what I've read, it's optional and is only required for BitLocker (which I don't use). There's no way to recreate it now, it seems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the boot files on the SSD, use something like:

```
bcdboot C:\windows /s D: /f all /l en-US
```

where

`C:\windows` = a valid Windows Installation to take files from

`/s D:` = The drive letter of the partition which you want to use as the boot disk

`/f all` = installs boot files for both BIOS and UEFI, just in case.

`/l en-GB` = the language of the files to use, `en-US` is the default.

after that you may have to add/edit entries in the new BCD store, use `bcdedit.exe` for that.

Comment: Thanks. I used EasyBCD according to [instruction on 7forums](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/209885-bootmgr-move-c-easybcd.html): BCD backup/repair > Change boot drive > Perform action. It gave me exact copy of the existing BCD store.